# Output multiple LESS source maps with Grunt?

Tags: css, less, gruntjs, source-maps

I have a Grunt file to compile my LESS file into a CSS file, and create a `css.map` file as well.  Great.

I have more than one LESS file I want to do this for though but I can't figure out the syntax to do both.

I have `theme.less` and `main.less` that I need
- compiled
- put into the right folder
- and a map file generated for each.

Right now I have this:

```
//LESS
    less: {
        development: {
            options: {
                compress: true,
                yuicompress: true,
                optimization: 2,
                sourceMap: true,
                sourceMapFilename: "<%= yeoman.app %>/live_preview/b/css/theme.css.map"

            },
            files: {
                // target.css file: source.less file
               // "<%= yeoman.app %>/live_preview/b/css/main.css": "<%= yeoman.app %>/less/main.less",
                "<%= yeoman.app %>/live_preview/b/css/theme.css": "<%= yeoman.app %>/less/theme.less"
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I commented out `main.less`. `Theme.less` compiles and the map file is created, but I'd like to do both...

Comment: Do you want `theme.less` and `main.less` to compile to `main.css`? Or, do you want `theme.less` to compile to `theme.css` and `main.less` to compile to `main.css`? Or, would you like something different?

Comment: I know how to get the 2 css files; my issue here is the map file for each.

Comment: Oh, I totally misread the question, makes more sense. The only way I can think of involves creating a second build process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crummy brute-force method is to simply define a second build process and make sure that your build processes call both `less.development1` and `less.development2`:

```
less: {
    "development1": {
        options: {
            compress: true,
            yuicompress: true,
            optimization: 2,
            sourceMap: true,
            sourceMapFilename: "<%= yeoman.app %>/live_preview/b/css/theme.css.map"

        },
        files: {
            // target.css file: source.less file
            "<%= yeoman.app %>/live_preview/b/css/theme.css": "<%= yeoman.app %>/less/theme.less"
        }
    },
    "development2": {
        options: {
            compress: true,
            yuicompress: true,
            optimization: 2,
            sourceMap: true,
            sourceMapFilename: "<%= yeoman.app %>/live_preview/b/css/main.css.map"

        },
        files: {
            // target.css file: source.less file
            "<%= yeoman.app %>/live_preview/b/css/main.css": "<%= yeoman.app %>/less/main.less"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to do this with grunt-contrib-less, see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/issues/89

Your only option is to inline your source maps in the CSS file by setting `outputSourceFiles:true` .  In my experience this is actually the most convenient way to handle your maps anyway.

The only downside is that it will require that you have a minifier set up, since inlining the maps will likely more than double the size of your CSS files but will be easily stripped by a minifier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
files: {
  'assets/css/main.min.css': [
    'assets/less/app.less',
    'assets/less/app2.less'
  ]
},
```

Let me know.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the question.  The question is I have multiple css files that i want to output a map file for each:
`file1.less --> file1.css, file1.cssmap` and
`file2.less --> file2.css, file2.cssmap`